# How to solve flutter issue

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I am getting an error code with my flutter app.

this is the erro code

../../../AppData/Local/flutter3.3.3-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_calendar_carousel-1.5.3/lib/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart:451:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'backgroundColor'.
backgroundColor:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/flutter3.3.3-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_button.dart:77:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const TextButton({
^^^^^^^^^^

name: infixedu
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 2.4.4+38

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
dio: ^4.0.0
equatable: ^2.0.3
file_picker: ^4.2.4
file_utils: ^0.1.3
flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
flutter_calendar_carousel: ^1.4.10
flutter_cupertino_date_picker_fork: 1.0.3
flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
flutter_webview_plugin:
git: https://github.com/jiankian/flutter_webview_plugin
fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
http: ^0.13.0
open_file: ^3.2.0
path_provider: ^2.0.1
rxdart: ^0.26.0
scoped_model: ^1.0.1
shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
uuid: ^3.0.0
shimmer: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
fancy_shimmer_image: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.3
age: ^0.0.1
intl: ^0.17.0
flutter_overlay_loader: ^0.1.1
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.1
timeago: ^3.0.2
flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0-nullsafety.0
font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
pdf_flutter:
git: https://github.com/erluxman/pdf_flutter
provider: ^6.0.0
cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
extended_image: 3.0.0
ffi: ^1.0.0
firebase_core: ^1.17.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.4.0
flutter_dropdown_alert: ^1.0.1
edge_alert: ^0.0.1
flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.7.0
permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
http_auth: ^1.0.1
flutter_paystack:
git:
url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01
flutter_credit_card: ^3.0.0
carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2
device_info_plus: ^3.1.0
package_info_plus: ^1.3.0
get: ^4.6.5
google_fonts: ^2.1.0
badges: ^2.0.1
themify_flutter: ^1.0.0
stripe_sdk: ^5.0.0-nullsafety.1
flutter_portal: ^0.4.0
loading_more_list: ^4.0.1
let_log: ^1.1.4
emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.0.8
flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.3
photo_view: ^0.13.0
better_player: ^0.0.77
flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.7
pdf: ^3.7.1
khalti: ^1.0.2
reorderables:
git: https://github.com/emran92/reorderables
pusher_channels_flutter: ^1.0.5

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.8+4
import_sorter: ^4.6.0

## flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

flutter_icons:
android: "launcher_icon"
ios: true
image_path: "assets/config/app_icon.jpg"

## flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create

flutter_native_splash:
image: assets/config/splash_logo.png
fullscreen: true
color: "FFFFFF"

flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:

- assets/config/
- assets/images/
- assets/locale/

fonts:

- family: popins
  fonts:

  - asset: fonts/poppins_medium.ttf
    weight: 100
  - asset: fonts/poppins_bold.ttf
    weight: 200
  - asset: fonts/poppins_light.ttf
    weight: 300
  - asset: fonts/poppins_regular.ttf
    weight: 400
  - asset: fonts/poppins_semibold.ttf
    weight: 500